# What Did IMDB Use to Code Their iPhone Trivia App?

Tags: iphone, xcode, imdb

Their app is very well done, however doesn't seem to use any of the normal controls that come standard with the framework.  Now it could be they just did an excellent job of restyling those components, but I'm thinking they used something like Adobe Air or something to code it which I think is allowed now whereas it wasn't in the past.

If anyone has any insight I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I would wager that most of the main UI is done as HTML and rendered using a web view. The rest looks like standard UI with custom images.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm an idiot...I meant their new Trivia App.  Since I'm new here, is there any way to change my subject line?  So sorry about that.

Comment: Ok, I found how to edit the subject line.  Thanks Jeff for answering according to my original subject line.  Let me know if you have any idea what they used in the new trivia app.

Comment: No worries. You could just post a new question.